# How to filter two DataTables in C#?

Tags: c#, filter, datatable

How to filter two tables in C#? Table one contains full data and table Two contains some content of Table one?

Comment: Provide your code please?

Comment: Visit http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/d1912b96-7a31-4cfc-b584-84309c4dcaea/ for your answer and please provide your code what you have tried so far .

Comment: You're question is not clear at all. Provide some code to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly do you want to do (it's not clear from your question)? Take table1, filter it and then pass the result to table2?
Then:

```
DataView dv = table1.AsDataView();
dv.RowFilter = fexpression; // for example "MyID = 3"
DataTable table2 = dv.ToTable();

// If you want typed datatable, you can do it like this (although there are other ways):
MyTypedDataTable table2 = new MyTypedDataTable();
DataTable tempTable = dv.ToTable();
table2.Merge(tempTable);
```